# Deleting A Listview Item Makes Images Out Of Order

Tags: android, firebase, listview, imageview

So here is how I am adding my images and text to the listview.

```
ArrayList<Integer> getList() {

//idImages = new ArrayList<>();


idImages.add(R.drawable.myhousech2image);
idImages.add(R.drawable.myhousech1image);
idImages.add(R.drawable.myhousech3image);

return idImages;

}

     ArrayList<String> getNameList() {

    //nameList = new ArrayList<>();



    nameList.add("Eat Snow");
    nameList.add("Stand In The Yard");
    nameList.add("Walk The Dog");

    return nameList;
}
```

I want to remove the image and text from the list using this. However this causes the app to crash because of and out of bounds exception when removing the drawable item.

```
        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {



        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


            if (dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).child("My House CH 1").exists()) {



                idImages.remove(R.drawable.myhousech2image);

                nameList.remove("Stand In The Yard");

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
```

I have gotten the images to remove, however I cannot remember which code I used. It did not work though because the images would no longer line up with the proper text. Also I think it would remove the image below the one that was supposed to be deleted.

Any advice on how to get this to work be great. Thanks!

Comment: Make a class that wraps both the name and its associated image. Build a ListView Adapter using that class...

Comment: Also, you're probably calling `list.remove(int index)` rather than `list.remove(Object item)`

Answer (score 0):

```
int INDEX=// index value of the Image
int INDEX2=// index value of the Name
idImages.remove(INDEX);
nameList.remove(INDEX2);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer . Code only answer is only meant to copy-Paste its not helpful.